# change address of object that keeps raw pointer to its field

Tags: c++, c++14, move, raw-pointer, memory-reallocation

I want to re-allocate a class that has self-reference, named `CarJoker`.
"Re-allocate" here means = to change the address of an object.

This technique is necessary for making every instance of `CarJoker` lives in a resizable contiguous array e.g. pool.

I think about using `std::move`, but it can't move `CarJoker::wheels` in a way that I wish.
([MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/113c39e8bc5e93c9))

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct Wheel{
    void setBlade(){}
    void setTwinkle(){}
};
struct CarJoker{
    Wheel wa;
    Wheel wb;
    Wheel wc;
    std::vector<Wheel*> wheels;
    float hp=5;
    CarJoker(){
        wheels.push_back(&wa);
        wheels.push_back(&wb);
        wheels.push_back(&wc);
    }
    void wow(){
        //v want to apply something to every "wheel"
        for(auto wheel:wheels){
            wheel->setBlade();
        }
        //v want to apply something to some certain "wheel"
        wa.setTwinkle();
    }
};

int main(){
    CarJoker car1;
    CarJoker car2=std::move(car1);
    std::cout<<"want to 1 : "<<(car2.wheels[0]== &car2.wa)<<std::endl;
}
```

With `std::move`, `car2.wheels[0]` points to `&car1.wa` not `&car2.wa` as I wish.
I know the reason, but that is not my goal, and I don't know an elegant way to fix it.

### My poor workaround

Here is an inelegant way ([MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4e0033ef725b168)):-

```
struct CarJoker{
    Wheel wa;
    Wheel wb;
    Wheel wc;
    std::vector<Wheel*> wheels;
    float hp=5;
    CarJoker(){
        reIni();  //: CHANGE (call a new function)
    }
    void reIni(){ //: CHANGE (create a new function)
        wheels.clear();
        wheels.push_back(&wa);
        wheels.push_back(&wb);
        wheels.push_back(&wc);
    }
    void wow(){
        //v want to apply something to every "wheel"
        for(auto wheel:wheels){
            wheel->setBlade();
        }
        //v want to apply something to some certain "wheel"
        wa.setTwinkle();
    }
};
int main(){
    CarJoker car1;
    CarJoker car2=std::move(car1);
    car2.reIni(); //: CHANGE (call a new function)
    std::cout<<"want to 1 : "<<(car2.wheels[0]== &car2.wa)<<std::endl;
}
```

**Disadvantage:-**
1. It is dirty.
2. I have to create a special-name function (`reIni()`) for every class that has such symptom that live in the pool.      My pool has to recognize that function too (e.g. register using template or virtual function).

### My poor workaround 2

```
 struct CarJoker{
    Wheel wa;
    Wheel wb;
    Wheel wc;
    std::vector<Wheel*> getWheels(){  //use this instead of "wheels"
        std::vector<Wheel*> re;
        re.push_back(&wa);
        re.push_back(&wb);
        re.push_back(&wc);
        return re;
    }
    ....
 }
```

I would work, but I feel that it is crazy to workaround like this.
The restriction increases pitfall for coders.

If `wheels` happen to need to cache computation-expensive result, now it would be expensive to call `getWheels()` often.

Comment: Do you need `wheels` to store pointers?

Comment: An idea like not having internal variables like `wa`, `wb` or `wc` and just have `wheels` store the actual instances of `Wheel` comes to mind.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Yes, it would work.  Now, I have to `getWa(){return wheels[0];}` which is not so elegant.

Comment: If you need a getter function like that, you'd have to define 3 of them either way. Why not something like `getWheel(int w) {return wheels.at(w);}` ? That way you only have one general getter function, only one `Wheel` container, and you avoid the initial problem altogether.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Because each wheel is unique. I want to refer it by name rather than index.

Comment: Then I honestly don't see why the `getWa(){return wheels[0];}` approach is that bad.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Agree, it is not inherently bad.  It is just not fool-proof.  Moderately-sane coder will not recognize that my original `CarJoker` is wrong.   By code alone, he can't notice it as an error because `std::move` is in a far away `.cpp`.  So while it works for this case, it still open room for new error of this kind.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `reIni()` method. What you need is to add:

- a copy constructor and a move constructor which both initialize the `wheels` member the same way as the default constructor does.
- a copy assignment operator and a move assignment operator which do not copy/move the `wheels` member.

Try this:

```cpp
struct CarJoker{
    Wheel wa;
    Wheel wb;
    Wheel wc;
    std::vector<Wheel*> wheels;
    float hp = 5;

    CarJoker(){
        wheels.push_back(&wa);
        wheels.push_back(&wb);
        wheels.push_back(&wc);
    }

    CarJoker(const CarJoker &src) :
        CarJoker(),
        wa(src.wa),
        wb(src.wb),
        wc(src.wc),
        //wheels(src.wheels),
        hp(src.hp){
    }

    CarJoker(CarJoker &&src) :
        CarJoker(),
        wa(std::move(src.wa)),
        wb(std::move(src.wb)),
        wc(std::move(src.wc)),
        //wheels(std::move(src.wheels)), 
        hp(src.hp){
    }

    // copy assignment and move assignment can be
    // handled with a single implementation that
    // lets the compiler choose between the copy
    // constructor and move constructor as needed...
    CarJoker& operator=(CarJoker rhs){
        wa = std::move(rhs.wa);
        wb = std::move(rhs.wb);
        wc = std::move(rhs.wc);
        wheels = std::move(rhs.wheels);
        hp = rhs.hp;
        return *this;
    }

    ...
};
```

That being said, you really shouldn't be using self-referencing fields to begin with. A single `std::array<Wheel, 3>` field makes more sense than 3 `Wheel` fields and a `std::vector<Wheel*>` field, avoiding this whole problem.

```cpp
struct CarJoker{
    std::array<Wheel, 3> wheels;
    float hp = 5;

    CarJoker() = default;
    CarJoker(const CarJoker&) = default;
    CarJoker(CarJoker&&) = default;
    CarJoker& operator=(const CarJoker&) = default;
    CarJoker& operator=(CarJoker&&) = default;

    Wheel& wa() { return wheels[0]; }
    const Wheel& wa() const { return wheels[0]; }

    Wheel& wb() { return wheels[1]; }
    const Wheel& wb() const { return wheels[1]; }

    Wheel& wc() { return wheels[2]; }
    const Wheel& wc() const { return wheels[2]; }

    void wow(){
        //v want to apply something to every "wheel"
        for(auto &wheel : wheels){
            wheel.setBlade();
        }

        //v want to apply something to some certain "wheel"
        wa().setTwinkle();
    }
};
```

Comment: Look like an expert approach.  Thank.   In this approach, in the copy/move, I have to manually copy/move field by field - line by line. (e.g. I have to copy `wa`,`wb`,`wc` manually) It is error-prone. ?

Comment: After your edit, the uber-uglyness appears on surface.  >.<

Comment: @javaLover yes, you have to manually copy/move relevant fields since you want to pick&choose which fields to copy/move and which to not. And in all honesty, your `wheels` field makes no sense and should be rewritten to avoid this whole situation. A single `std::array<Wheel, 3>` field makes more sense than 3 `Wheel` fields and a `std::vector<Wheel*>` field

Comment: Can I kinda override it partially e.g.  `CarJoker& operator=(CarJoker rhs){ DO_COPY_DEFAULT; reIni(); }`  ?

Comment: @javaLover you could, but I wouldn't do that.